# how to check whether a context is valid?

Tags: java, android, exception, android-context

I am writing a method in my `Android` lib, which accepts `Context` as one of the parameters.
Now I want to check if someone does not send an invalid context like

```
Context context = new Activity();
```

Since I am using that context to get info, sending context from above ends up a `NullPointerException` in `Contextwrapper` class.
I want to check if that context is invalid before doing any operation.
So there will be no exception in this.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856103/how-can-i-tell-if-my-context-is-still-valid

Comment: you may try to perform an operation with it in a `try...catch` block, and do something in case of exceptions. For example, get some resource

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko try catch is one solution, by handling the exception and throwing other, but what if the same exception has been occurred due to other reason and I will be sending wrong information back to users. I want to know if there is way to get info from context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell if my context is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856103/how-can-i-tell-if-my-context-is-still-valid)